# How to extract product id or name from paypal IPN transaction

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

im currently developing an online shopping store. For this website, I did not store any cart history into my database, therefore I do not have any details about customer orders. I plan to get the order details right after the customer made payment.

My problem now is my product are sent as array to paypal and every transactions are saved into my database table field as below:

**20-1,21-1**

20 and 21 are the products id, and right next to it are the quantity.

I need to know is it possible for me to retrieve orders only from paypal IPN without creating a specific database to store orders from customer?

Please i really need your help on this

```
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode the string, make it an array, then query all the prices out, add them up, and make sure they match the payment_gross amount
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string); // Uses Comma(,) as delimiter(break point)
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value); // Uses Hyphen(-) as delimiter to separate product ID from its quantity
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // Get the quantity
    $query = "SELECT price FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $product_price = $row["price"];
    }
    $product_price = $product_price * $product_quantity;
    $fullAmount = $fullAmount + $product_price;
}
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
$grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross']; 
if ($fullAmount != $grossAmount) {
        $message = "Possible Price Jack: " . $_POST['mc_gross'] . " != $fullAmount \n\n\n$req";
        mail("email@gmail.com", "Price Jack or Bad Programming", $message, "From: email@gmail.com" );
        exit(); // exit script
} 
// END ALL SECURITY CHECKS NOW IN THE DATABASE IT GOES ------------------------------------
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Assign local variables from the POST PayPal variables
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['payment_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];

// Place the transaction into the database
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO transactions (id, product_id_array, payer_email, first_name, last_name, payment_date, mc_gross, payment_currency, receiver_email, payment_type, payment_status, txn_type, payer_status, address_street, address_city, address_state, address_zip, address_country, address_status, notify_version, verify_sign, payer_id, mc_currency, mc_fee) 
   VALUES('$txn_id','$custom','$payer_email','$first_name','$last_name','$payment_date','$mc_gross','$payment_currency','$receiver_email','$payment_type','$payment_status','$txn_type','$payer_status','$address_street','$address_city','$address_state','$address_zip','$address_country','$address_status','$notify_version','$verify_sign','$payer_id','$mc_currency','$mc_fee')") or die ("unable to execute the query");

mysqli_close();
// Mail yourself the details
mail("email@gmail.com", "New Order Entered: ".$txn_id, $req, "From: email@gmail.com");
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps I've not understood, but you can add full description in request using `item_namex` field or can retrieve description after the payment with the query you use to retrieve the price for checking.  
But beside this consider that a transaction is a very important event and can be wise to save all values of all parameters related to a transaction when transaction occour: what happens if meanwhile somebody buys you change the price of the item? the FullAmount and GrossAmount will not match, but payment is right, finally check fullamount and gross_amount is not enough

Comment: need to check clearly if response is not INVALID, that it is not a sandbox payment (test_ipn!=1) that receiver_email is your paypal email address, that txn_id has not already been processed, and that payment_status = completed

Comment: The above code is just a snippet from my full code. The response is valid, and the price matched the full amount and gross amount. My problem now is how am i suppose to extract product details from array field